# "'1.0.0' is not a valid short file name" when installing Xamarin IOS.Setup and Android.Setup

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

When i try to install the new Xamarin updates 1.8 i get the following error:

> '1.0.0' is not a valid short file name.

Screenshot:

[image: Xamarin error]

Does someone knows what to do to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe you have to contact with xamarin....Look at this http://xamarin.vanillaforums.com/discussion/10164/new-updates-ios-and-android-installer-fails[/link]

Comment: They are not responding

Comment: Thats me already tried and not working

Comment: That's odd..Have you tried to install it to another pc and see if the problem still goes on?

Comment: Tryed to install on local instead of Domain user even not working can't install other pc license thats why still trailling and i have admin account aswell

Comment: that's too sad :/ Try to contact them sending them lot's of emails.I do not think it is a common problem and someone here will help you!Send them to give you another license,because that's their problem,not yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem, try this:

Uninstall xamarin components that this error appears with this tool:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971187/en-us
(Can take long time, wait...)

Then install new Xamarin itens.