# Error in installing Xamarin: Error 1325 ('1.0.0' is not a valid short file name)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I had Xamarin.Android installed on my Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012. 
I installed VS 2013 last week, and I had to remove VS 2012. 
Then I wanted to install Xamarin 3, and since then I cannot get pass this error. 
I have removed all components that are related to Xamarin, except Xamarin.Android
When I try to remove Xamarin.Android I get this same error again.

Any help would be appreciated, I cannot remove Xamarin.Android, niether can I do a fresh installation.

```
[Info] === Logging started: 2/06/2014  16:49:33 ===
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: INSTALL.
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: FindRelatedProducts.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:33: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: AppSearch.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:33: AppSearch. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: LaunchConditions.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:33: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: SetVS2012_ROOT_FOLDER.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:33: SetVS2012_ROOT_FOLDER. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: ValidateProductID.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:33: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: CostInitialize.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:33: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: FileCost.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:33: FileCost. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: CostFinalize.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:33: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: MigrateFeatureStates.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:33: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
[Info] Action start 16:49:33: InstallValidate.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:34: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:34: RemoveExistingProducts.
[Info] Action start 16:49:34: INSTALL.
[Info] Action start 16:49:34: AppSearch.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:34: AppSearch. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:34: FindRelatedProducts.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:34: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
[Info] Action start 16:49:34: LaunchConditions.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:34: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:34: SetVS2012_ROOT_FOLDER.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:34: SetVS2012_ROOT_FOLDER. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:34: ValidateProductID.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:34: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:34: CostInitialize.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:34: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:34: FileCost.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:34: FileCost. Return value 1.
[Info] Action start 16:49:34: CostFinalize.
[Info] MSI (s) (54:44) [16:49:34:848]: Product: Xamarin.Android -- Error 1325. '1.0.0' is not a valid short file name.
[Info] Error 1325. '1.0.0' is not a valid short file name.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:34: CostFinalize. Return value 3.
[Info] Action ended 16:49:34: INSTALL. Return value 3.
[Info] Property(N): UpgradeCode = {93EC4CB5-3AF9-4041-9413-E5F304933393}
[Info] Property(N): VS2013DEVENV = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
[Info] Property(N): VS2010_ROOT_FOLDER = c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\
[Info] Property(N): VS2012_ROOT_FOLDER = C:\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
[Info] Property(N): VS2013_ITEMTEMPLATES_DIR = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\
[Info] Property(N): VS2013_PROJECTTEMPLATES_DIR = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\
[Info] Property(N): VS2013_ROOT_FOLDER = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
[Info] Property(N): VS2013_EXTENSIONS_DIR = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\
[Info] Property(N): HAVE_PCL = C:\
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for Xamarin tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Xamarin support and followed the steps they provided 6 times or more with no luck, then finally I found this answer on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115653/1-0-0-is-not-a-valid-short-file-name-when-installing-xamarin-ios-setup-and-a/23922777#23922777)),

I had to uninstall all Xamarin components (Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Studio, etc), then remove all related files manually, then run Microsoft tool Fix-it ([can be found here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971187/en-us)), only then a reinstall worked fine.

Hope this would help somebody else who faces a similar issue